# Qual código de status HTTP usar para indicar falha de validação?

Tags: http, http-status

Quando um método em uma API web detecta que houve falha na validação dos dados de uma entidade a ser adicionada ou atualizada existe algum código HTTP que seja padrão de ser enviado? Por enquanto estou usando o código 400 (bad request), mas não sei se existe outro mais recomendado pra esse tipo de falha.

Comment: Essa pergunta é boa, mas acredito que seja baseada em opiniões devido ao fato das RFCs não serem claras nesse ponto, sendo possível haver várias interpretações, e, portanto, opiniões sobre qual é o código adequado.

Comment: O Pablo tem razão, mas acho que pode ter sim uma resposta específica baseada no consenso geral.

Answer (score 5):

Sua pergunta é boa, mas, no entanto, acredito que ela seja baseada em opiniões. A escolha do código adequado deve ser feita em função do que estabelece a RFC em vigor. No entanto, como qualquer outra norma, nem sempre a RFC é clara, sendo possível interpretá-la de várias maneiras.

Segue as minhas considerações sobre as respostas já dadas e a minha opinião.

### 1. Em que e onde devo procurar fontes para perguntas como essa?

Em primeiro lugar, a RFC que diz respeito a isso e que está em voga no momento é a [7231](http://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231.txt). Se tiver familiaridade com inglês, sugiro que a leia para criar suas próprias opiniões também.

### 2. Sobre não utilizar código 200

Embora em algumas frameworks para web retornem 200 no caso de requisições com dados inválidos, não acredito que esse deva ser o código adequado.

De acordo com o item 6.3 da 7231, códigos 2xx indicam que a requisição do cliente foi recebida, compreendida e aceita.

Logo, se o objetivo de uma requisição POST é, por exemplo, criar um novo objeto no servidor e isso não é feito em função de dados inválidos, não considero que deva ser retornado o código 200 dizendo que a requisição foi um sucesso, mas sim um código que indique que algum erro ocorreu no processamento dos dados enviados.

### 3. Sobre utilizar o código 400

Se pensarmos que os dados enviados também fazem parte da requisição, se eles estiverem inválidos e, portanto errados, nada mais justo que retornar um código 400, que indica uma má requisição.

#### Definição do método POST

Olhando a definição do método POST na RFC fortalece essa ideia. De acordo com o item 4.3.3, uma requisição POST está pedindo para que um determinado recurso (ou *resource*) processe os dados presentes na requisição de acordo com a semântica do recurso. Logo, se você envia um dado que que não possui significado para servidor, a requisição não será entendida e não deverá ser processada.

#### Definição da classe 4xx e do código 400

Outro argumento para fortalecer o uso do código 400 é a definição da classe 4xx e sua própria definição:

A classe 4xx possui códigos para quando o cliente comete algum erro. Se você entende que o cliente é responsável pelo envio de dados válidos (e que a validação no servidor é feita por medida de segurança) 4xx parece ser a classe adequada. É importante notar que a classe 4xx, de acordo com a RFC, deve sempre retornar uma explicação do erro para o cliente.

O código 400, por sua vez, indica que o servidor não pode, não é capaz ou simplesmente não irá processar a requisição por erro do cliente (o erro de enviar dados que não possuem significado de acordo com o recurso solicitado).

É importante lembrar que a RFC não lista os erros que um cliente pode cometer, listando apenas alguns exemplos (erro de sintaxe é um deles).

### 4. Logo...

Concluindo, o cliente é responsável por enviar dados que façam sentido para o servidor, e, se não faz, isso deve ser considerado um erro do cliente. Portanto, sugiro que **utilize o código 400** e, como previsto na RFC, envie uma mensagem explicando o erro, dizendo que os dados não são válidos.

---

**Bônus: Métodos que definitivamente você não deve utilizar**

418: não é um código presente na RFC em vigor e não possui nenhum valor semântico para validação de dados.

405: deve ser usado apenas quando o *método* da requisição não é aceito pelo servidor e não os dados em si.

Answer (score 2):

## Aviso de opinião

**Essa resposta expressa a minha opinião e de maneira alguma representa uma interpretação oficial ou mais correta.**

## Erro 400

RFC 7321

> The 400 (Bad Request) status code indicates that the server cannot or
>      will not process the request due to something that is perceived to be
>      a client error (e.g., malformed request syntax, invalid request
>      message framing, or deceptive request routing).

O erro 400 significa que o servidor recusa-se a processar a requisição devido a um erro por parte do *client-side* e não há problema algum em usar ele. Eu, pessoalmente, prefiro manter ele para erros na requisição em si, e não para seus dados. Alguma bibliotecas podem enviar *bug reports* automáticos por padrão devido a essa resposta.

## 200 - OK

Você pode enviar a resposta como 200, informando que a requisição ocorreu com sucesso, o que é verdade. E então no conteúdo da resposta escrever se a API validou ou não e quais foram os erros. Essa é a opção que eu uso e recomendo, já que gosto de separar a requisição em si dos dados dela.

## 405 - Método não permitido

Acredito ser a segunda melhor opção, aqui vai a descrição oficial traduzida:

> Foi feita uma solicitação de um recurso usando um método de pedido que não é compatível com esse pedido.

Exemplo: usando GET em um formulário, que exige que os dados sejam apresentados via POST.

## 418 - Eu sou um bule de chá

Esse status foi criado como uma pegadinha de primeiro de abril e é inutil, então acho que como ele não tem uso, você poderia atribuir um uso "especial" para ele.

Comment: A RFC 7231 não diz nada a respeito de low-level e tampouco lista os erros que um cliente pode cometer, apenas cita exemplos. Logo não há problema algum em utilizar o 400 conforme você sugere. Além disso, o cliente deveria garantir que os dados enviados para o servidor estão válidos. Dessa forma o sistema para reportar bugs automáticos continuaria sendo útil em te dizer que o cliente não está está validando corretamente. Fora isso, o servidor deve prover uma mensagem adequada para o erro de processamento ocorrido, não havendo dúvidas para o desenvolvedor do cliente.

Comment: @PabloPalácios Obrigado pela informação acabei de reler o RFC e vou editar a resposta.

Answer (score 1):

Pode usar o 400 mesmo.
A definição em http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html diz:

> The request could not be understood by the server due to malformed
>   syntax. The client SHOULD NOT repeat the request without
>   modifications.

traduzindo...

> A solicitação não pôde ser entendida pelo servidor devido à sintaxe
>   mal formada. O cliente não deve repetir a solicitação sem
>   modificações.

Comment: Lucas, cuidado com sua fonte pois a RFC 2616 está obsoleta e foi quebrada em várias outras. A RFC 7231 é a que está em voga e que diz respeito sobre o assunto dessa questão.

Comment: Reforço também que deve ter cuidado com isso. Veja que a pergunta é clara referente a erros em parâmetros e não a erros no protocolo. O uso do erro 400 é para erros de sintaxe, por exemplo, um header que tenha erro de digitação como "contnt-type".. o correto seria "content-type".. Entendeu? Isso causa um erro 400 pela má formatação. Não tem relação alguma com parâmetros providos por GET, POST, PUT, DELETE..

Comment: @DanielOmine a nova RFC não deixa explicito qual tipo de erro deve ser retornado, dando como exemplo erros de sintaxe.